# How to support On Screen Touch keyboard in Hololens 2 DirectX12 App

Tags: uwp, hololens

I am trying to integrate Hololens2 into our custom rendering engine(Directx12 APIs). I am trying to show the Hololens TouchScreen keyboard when our Input Text Box becomes active.
I see that Microsoft documentation, that we need to switch from our Volumetric App's view to a XAML 2D view with TextBoxControl to show the system keyboard and take the input from there and come back to our main App and paste the contents in the our custom InputTextBox. Is that the only way to show Hololens TouchScreen keyboard?
Or we can show the touchscreen keyboard overlaid on our Volumetric app scene itself? I am able to show the Hololens2 Touchscreen keyboard in our Volumetric app view using InputPane APIs and CoreTextEditContext APIs. But I am not able to get the Keystroke events when I touch the onscreen keyboard. I have implemented all the event callbacks for the CoreWindow and CoreTextEditContext like KeyDown(), KeyUp(), TextUpdating() etc. But these callbacks are not getting called. I suppose, its because the CoreWindow text field is not there..

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using the system keyboard in the DirectX scene, I believe that the hard way provided by Rob Caplan in this thread should work for you:[Bringing up the soft keyboard in a Windows Phone 8.1 Direct3D app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30141259/bringing-up-the-soft-keyboard-in-a-windows-phone-8-1-direct3d-app).

In short, Windows uses the UI Automation API to identify and interact with text controls. Therefore, you need to implement the TextPattern and focus for your own text box UI control in DirectX by providing the [UI Automation text patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384841(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Text Service Framework (TSF) interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tsf/text-services-framework?redirectedfrom=MSDN), then the keyboad will automatically invoke when the user sets focus to it.

Comment: Apps do not receive this event when an Input Method Editor (IME) is enabled. The Input Method Editor (IME) handles all keyboard input and sets Handled to true. Hololens has english language IME by default enable and you can't disable it.that's why CoreWindow.CharacterReceived does not work. only one way is left that is to implement  UI Automation text patterns and Text Service Framework (TSF) interfaces but Mircosoft has not given any sample so that I can get the clear idea to implemet  UI Automation text patterns and Text Service Framework (TSF) interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem of not getting keyboard events in my Holographic View without use of single line of xaml code and Now I am able to show On Screen Touch keyboard in holographic View and I can get text input in my own custom TextBox. I was working on it from couple of days and i did not have any idea of UWP APIs. I struggled a lot and asked here and on slack but nobody could help me to solve my problem but today I got solution by doing experiments with xaml sample code so if anyone is also facing same problem then follow below Implementation

```
 CoreTextEditContext textEditContext = 
 CoreTextServicesManager.GetForCurrentView().CreateEditContext();
 textEditContext.TextUpdating += Context_TextUpdating;
```

These below two Event Callbacks Must be Implement to get keypress events such as CoreWindow.CharacterReceived,CoreWindow.KeyDown, CoreWindow.KeyUp on your CoreWindow. I was not getting these events because I did not implement them.

```
textEditContext.TextRequested += Context_TextRequested;
textEditContext.SelectionRequested += Context_SelectionRequested;
```

Here you tell TextService that you will show and hide keyboard your own by calling InputPane.TryShow and InputPane.TryHide APIs.

```
textEditContext.InputPaneDisplayPolicy = CoreTextInputPaneDisplayPolicy.Manual;

textEditContext.InputScope = CoreTextInputScope.Text;
```

get Instance of your On Screen KeyBoard and register keyboard hide and show events

```
InputPane OSDKeyboard = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
OSDKeyboard.Showing += OSDKeyboard_Showing;
OSDKeyboard.Hiding += OSDKeyboard_Hiding;
```

CoreTextEditContext Event Callbacks'  Implementation. CoreWindow started to work because of below functions otherwise I was not getting anything when i was pressing keys on touch keyboard

```
private void Context_SelectionRequested(CoreTextEditContext 
sender,CoreTextSelectionRequestedEventArgs args)
{

   var sel = new CoreTextRange();
   sel.StartCaretPosition = 0;
   sel.EndCaretPosition = 4;
   args.Request.Selection = sel;
}

private void Context_TextRequested(CoreTextEditContext sender, 
CoreTextTextRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    args.Request.Text = "Holographic_OnScreen_Keyboard";
}
```

Now you can show on screen keyboard by below lines of code. Press Any key on touch keyboard,you will get pressed key code in your registered callbacks of events CoreWindow.CharacterRecieved and CoreWindow.KeyDown. from where you can take text input in your hololens 2 App.

```
textEditContext.NotifyFocusEnter();
OSDKeyboard.TryShow();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.core.coretexteditcontext?view=winrt-19041

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane?view=winrt-19041